# Dokan запрашивает открытие папки как файла

Tags: c#, .net, файловая-система

У меня в файловой системе все данные хранятся в ОЗУ. Я создал папку, в которую скопировал файл. Проводник видит все нормально, папку как папку, файл как файл, но вот когда я файл открываю происходит 3 запроса:
[image: 1 запрос][image: 2 запрос][image: 3 запрос]
2 запроса на доступ к файлу и последний на доступ к папке где находится файл. Почему он обращается к папке как к файлу? Нет attributes directory, стоит info.isDirectory false. Все как у файла прописано и моя файловая система выдает что такого файла нет и при открытии файла получается что проводник пишет что неверное имя папки. Может есть где информация по тому как работает проводник, зачем он делает те или иные запросы доступа к файлам/папкам, почему щас обратился к папке как к файлу и почему тот же файл через Notepad++ открылся нормально, но при открытии сначала запрашивает буфер 126976 на что ему отвечают что не степень двойки или слишком большой, а потом 4096 и так по кругу пока весь файл не считает. Кроме того в папке почему-то я не могу создавать файлы, а только папки и от имени админа, хотя аттрибуты никакие не добавлял, все как было, все как передал проводник. До этого у меня была другая система хранения файлов и папок в ОЗУ и нормально все открывалось и запросы шли к папкам как к папкам, но были проблемы, например в каждой папке были файлы из всех папок и подобные несовершенства системы из-за чего я все переделывал и не пойму где ошибся. Полный код: https://pastebin.com/QZqZTgpS

Comment: у вас вопросы по коду, что вы не показали.

Comment: @tym32167 не знаю какие части кода дать, поэтому дал ссылку на полный код

Comment: Я даже не знаю в какую сторону искать. Дебажил каждую строчку и все равно нихера не пойму. Старый код удалил к сожалению, он был как тестовый и я не думал что такое случится.